# touch or click/drag to draw arbitrary area on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am familiar with how to draw circles and polygons on a Google Map using the javascript API. However, I've been looking at some android apps that allow you to "touch and draw" a freehand area on a map, not a collection of polyline/points or geometric shapes.

Is this functionality accessible to the js API? If so, how? I only find documentation on the polygons etc.

Note: this type of [functionality](http://www.daftlogic.com/sandbox-google-maps-marker-lasso-search-tool.htm) is not what I'm looking for! Clicking at multiple points to define an area is fine, but I'm trying to do a real "drawing" style.

Thanks

Comment: are you sure they are not polygons?

Comment: Well, I suppose they could just be polygons with a huge number of points-- the interface feels very smooth. What would you think? They are using a standard click/drag event but recording the points from it extremely frequently?

Comment: i don't have direct knowledge of that, but yes, i would suspect that you could just define an arbitrary region by either polyline or a set of polygons. (or some b-spline)

Comment: Related question: [Google Maps Draw — draw line or polygon by dragging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547900/google-maps-draw-draw-line-or-polygon-by-dragging)