# Freehand polygon drawing google maps mobile - Not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, mobile, polygon, touch-event

I am trying to implement a function that allows a user on a mobile device (using chrome or safari for example) to be able to draw a polygon in google maps.
The drawing function works just fine on a computer.
I suspect my issue is that the touch events are not recognized by Google event listeners.

**For example the standard computer function:**

```
window.google.maps.event.addListener(
        map,
        'mousemove',
        function (e) {
            console.log(e)
            poly.getPath().push(e.latLng);
        }
    );
```

**Then the mobile function (which does not work):**
The function isn't even called as the 'touchmove' event isn't recognized.

```
let move = window.google.maps.event.addListener(
        map,
        'touchmove',   
        function (e) {
            console.log(e) 
            poly.getPath().push(e.latLng);
        }
    );
```

Basic Example available on CodeSandbox here: [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/map-touch-zfoii)

It does seem from the Google Docs that touch events aren't supported:
[Google Maps - Events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events)

If that is the case, there must be some form of workaround.  Companies like Zillow.com and compass.com did implement a similar solution.  See screenshots below:
[image: Compass.com]
[image: zillow.com]

Appreciate any assistance.

Comment: The list of available events is here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map-Events

Comment: @MrUpsidown, I remember you and I exchanged "words" in the past.  I already went through this list and the relevant event documentation as per my post.   It's possible I could have missed something, could you please clarify what you are referring to specifically about your provided link?

Comment: Well you're trying to use an event that doesn't exist... You provided 2 screenshots but no links to the maps. Have you checked their code? How do they do it? DrawingManager does not have a "freehand" drawing mode so I would suppose this is something you will have to handle on your own. Most probably you will need to simplify the drawing and convert it to a Polygon. What about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22758950/google-map-drawing-freehand)?

Comment: I also found [this article](https://techblog.geekyants.com/a-brief-how-to-on-freehand-sketching-on-google-maps) and [this one](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5294895/Freehand-Drawing-using-Google-Map-and-Spatial-Sear) and [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/mX3VQ/). Also you might need to adjust [gesture handling](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/interaction#controlling_gesture_handling) for mobile.

Comment: Thank you.  I will work through the various links and post the solution as soon as I managed to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Google does recognize the "touchstart" event which for my purpose was all I needed.

Created 2x functions, one for on "mousedown" and one for "touchstart".  Rest of the functionality remains virtually unchanged.

```
// On mouse click
window.google.maps.event.addDomListener(
      map.getDiv(),
      "mousedown",
      function (e) {
        drawFreeHandMouse(map, polygonRef);
      }
    );

// on mobile device screen touch
window.google.maps.event.addDomListener(
      map.getDiv(),
      "touchstart",
      function (e) {
        drawFreeHandHand(map, polygonRef);
      }
    );
```

Full working solution can be viewed here:
[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/map-touch-zfoii?file=/components/Drawing.js&resolutionWidth=320&resolutionHeight=675)

Hopefully this can help somebody else or can be improved upon.