# Google maps - draw area for searching

Tags: google-maps, coordinates, area

I need to search an object in the area, which is drawn by user.

There are api for drawing rectangles, circles, polygons, etc.

But how to implement free drawing area on map?

It must work on mobile.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps Draw — draw line or polygon by dragging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547900/google-maps-draw-draw-line-or-polygon-by-dragging)

Comment: But this solution (right mouse) will not work on mobile device...

Comment: There is no mention of mobile devices in your question.

Comment: It's done in an mobile application. Can it be done with Google Maps sdk for Android and iOS?

Answer (score 0):

I have understood.

Just use code from [Google Maps Draw -- draw line or polygon by dragging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547900/google-maps-draw-draw-line-or-polygon-by-dragging)

But set map's options to draggable: false, during drawing.